# Commit nHibernate transaction in background in ASP.NET application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nhibernate

Is it possible to commit a transaction in the background while already returning the view to the user when using nHibernate in an ASP.NET MVC application?

So upon reaching "ActionExecuted", which is normally the point at which the transaction is committed when using the session-per-request pattern, I want to continue right away while nHibernate starts committing. This would allow the user to see the resulting view earlier.

Comment: You mean like doing it asynchronously to avoid blocking the processing?

Comment: Yes, I suppose you could say it like that.

Comment: If you show a result to the user pretending everything is finished, when in fact the transaction could still fail to commit, it feels like you are lying to the user?

Comment: I kind of agree with the previous comment. Not about lying but things could still fail.. isn't that an issue with your app? I mean it could not be an issue if you just send something like 'request submitted' and then the result could be expected somewhere else.. If that's the case, why not doing just async calls within the app instead of trying to use NHibernate asynchronously?

Comment: Oskar, Sergio, you're right of course. There are several risks involved. However, currently committing the results takes about half the time or more of the total request due to a large amount of inserts and updates. So I'm looking for a solution to that. If someone knows a better alternative, I'm al ears of course.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of committing in the background (which you can do with a Thread, as long as you make sure the session gets cleaned afterwards), why not switch to a queue-based architecture?

Advantages:

- It's actually designed for what you want, not a hack
- You can scale out as far as you want (same app, different app, different server, different datacenter...)
- If you build it correctly, it can offer even more reliability than a straight-to-db approach

Of course, there is a cost, which is creating the DTOs for the queue and then building the actual transaction. And also, the request is not really finished when you return control to the user (this is non-deterministic. The next request might find the data in the db or not)

Comment: Diego, something like this might help. I've found an article by Ayende which might be interesting: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff796225.aspx

Comment: The article describes a smart client architecture, not a Web one. A good read anyway, and it does talk about queues.